# Glossaries table of contents showing acronyms where only long forms were used

Tags: table-of-contents, glossaries

In a document where some acronyms are defined, and only long versions are used throughout the document, is it possible to have these long forms not show in the list of acronyms?

MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[toc,xindy,acronym,shortcuts,nomain]{glossaries}

\newacronym{test1}{T1}{test1}
\newacronym{test2}{T2}{test2}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\printglossaries

This is \acrlong{test1} and this is \gls{test2}.

\end{document}
```

To clarify, what I am looking for is that after `pdflatex -> makeglossaries -> pdflatex`, T1 does not show in the list of acronyms. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `\glsentrylong` instead of `\acrlong`, the entry won't be indexed:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[toc,xindy,acronym,shortcuts,nomain]{glossaries}

\newacronym{test1}{T1}{test1}
\newacronym{test2}{T2}{test2}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\printglossaries

This is \glsentrylong{test1} and this is \gls{test2}.

\end{document}
```

This doesn't check for the existence of `test1` but you could define a command to perform this check in case you make a mistake when you type the label:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[toc,xindy,acronym,shortcuts,nomain]{glossaries}

\newacronym{test1}{T1}{test1}
\newacronym{test2}{T2}{test2}

\makeglossaries

\newcommand{\glsl}[1]{\glsdoifexists{#1}{\glsentrylong{#1}}}

\begin{document}
\printglossaries

This is \glsl{test1} and this is \gls{test2}.

\end{document}
```

[image: Image of document]

Another possibility is to create an "ignored" glossary (using `\newignoredglossary`) and put the entries that you don't want indexed in there.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}

\usepackage[acronymlists={acronym,ignoredacronyms},
  toc,xindy,acronym,shortcuts,nomain]{glossaries}

\newignoredglossary{ignoredacronyms}

\newacronym[type=ignoredacronyms]{test1}{T1}{test1}
\newacronym{test2}{T2}{test2}

\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
\printglossaries

This is \acrlong{test1} and this is \gls{test2}.

\end{document}
```

Comment: \glsentrylong is perfect, second approach requires per-document manual work that I like to avoid. Thanks!